# Stata - esttab and tabstat formatting

Tags: format, latex, cross-platform, decimal, stata

I am using `esttab` + `tabstat` to generate a `.tex` file to be opened in `LaTeX`.  I am close to getting what I want, but there is one issue:

How do I get my standard deviations on the same line after the means?  It currently shows up on the line following the mean.

A MWE follows.  Note that I am actually creating two tables and appending them on to each other.  This just shows up as two separate tables in `Stata`, but it works in `LaTeX` after I modify the code slightly so as to save to a file and not output to the screen.  If there is a way to not append as I do and just do everything at once, that would be super, but I am not aware of one.  Note also that I am following the code of [this site](http://www.jwe.cc/2012/03/stata-latex-tables-estout/) to go between the two programs.

```
sysuse auto, replace
*create new categorical variable
quietly gen mod= ""
quietly replace mod="odd" if mod(_n, 2) == 1 
quietly replace mod="even" if mod(_n, 2) == 0
*create table - by foreign
quietly eststo clear
quietly estpost tabstat price, by(foreign) statistics(mean sd) listwise nototal
quietly est store A
quietly estpost tabstat mpg, by(foreign) statistics(mean sd) listwise nototal
quietly est store B
esttab A B, main(mean 2) aux(sd 2) label  noobs parentheses ///
    varlabels(`e(labels)') mtitle("Mean price" "Mean mpg") nostar ///
    unstack nonote nonumber collabels(none) refcat(Domestic "Origin", nolabel)
*append to table - by mod   
quietly estpost tabstat price, by(mod) statistics(mean sd) listwise nototal
quietly est store A
quietly estpost tabstat mpg, by(mod) statistics(mean sd) listwise nototal
quietly est store B
esttab A B, append main(mean 2) aux(sd 2) label  noobs parentheses ///
varlabels(`e(labels)') mtitle("Mean price" "Mean mpg") nostar ///
    unstack nonote nonumber collabels(none) refcat(even "Type", nolabel)
```

**Update 1** I solved the problem that I had previously included in this question.  That problem had to do with decimal points not showing up in my `LaTeX` output.  But I was doing something wrong in `LaTeX` relating to the implementation of a package.  (I simply had to put in the correct number of columns.)

**Update 2** I figured out how to get the standard errors in parentheses: remove `plain` form the code.  I think it is default, but include the `parentheses` option.  I have updated the code and text to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply include `onecell` to the `esttab` code.  See the [documentation](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/hlp_esttab.html).